# Please change the home page / question list font back to the normal font

Tags: discussion, status-completed, design

I'm having a lot of trouble with the font on the home page.  I like the font in headings and buttons, but on the home page it's just too much.  I find it hard to skim through the list of questions the way I used to.

The home page now:

[image]

The home page with the same font used everywhere else on the site:

[image]

Comment: Give the design a chance. It's been there for all of 10 minutes now.

Comment: Maybe another font thats part way in between? I see two differences: style, and pixelated. By style I mean how the letters end in points, the 'b'/'d' do not extend all the way up, etc. I'd love if we could keep one of the two of those, but still improve readability?

Comment: +1, I like the retro look, but in this case it's just not very easy on the eyes.

Comment: @badp been discussing it with Jin internally, we decided to put it to the community

Comment: @david i think the font gives the site a lot more personality and fits the theme well. that being said, practicality > style. I'll leave the verdict to the community. and meanwhile I'll try to find an alternative, if not websafe font.

Comment: Related gripe: the font seems to has a scaling problem.  The `K` in `ASKED` (on the right sidebar) and the `Y` in `ACTIVITY` are botched.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have removed the pixel font on the homepage and question listing page. It is only used on the page titles and sidebar titles now.

Comment: Thanks Jin, its is a lot more readable now!

Answer (score 7):

I'm still not sure if I agree with that, but the [answers in one's profile](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/14/juan-manuel) sure look weird (too big and messy IMO)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The font works well for the headers, the tabs (Questions/Tags/Users ...), and might even work well for the links at the very top, but definitely not for the questions.